# EXTRACT for TIMESTAMP types in SQLite3

Tags: sqlite

It seems extract function is not supported by SQLite3 for timestamp types ([ref](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=UnsupportedSql)). For example;

```
select
 extract(year from l_shipdate) as l_year
from
 ...
```

gives the following error;
Error: near "from": syntax error

I wonder whether there is an alternative way to do this in SQLite3 (or through rewriting the SQL query).

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
select strftime('%Y', l_shipdate) as l_year from...
```